# I want to monitor a job triggered through emrserverlessstartjoboperator. If the job is either is success or failed, want to rerun the job in airflow

Tags: pyspark, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I want to monitor a job triggered which is already triggered through emrserverlessstartjoboperator.  If the job is either successful or failed, want to retrigger the same job in EMR.
Basically i want to know how to monitor a job status which is running/completed.
Then retrigger the same job in EMR.
thanks,
Mag